# Delta to star transform currents

Tags: current, ac, three-phase, y-to-delta

When we transform a delta circuit to a star circuit it is easy to transform the voltages and the resistances.

[image]

In the case of a delta circuit between current flows only between 2  nodes while in a star circuit current flows between 1 node and the ground.Which is the conversion for currents from a delta to a star circuit?

Answer (score 0):

The two circuits are defined to be equivalent if you do the transform correctly. So, **exactly** the same currents flow throught the three nodes marked with dots.

The whole point of the transform is that one of either might be easier to compute.

And, no, there's no ground anywhere in the star topology – otherwise, a ground symbol would be in there.

Answer (score 0):

If the star system is balanced no current will flow in the neutral wire. What comes in on one phase will go out on the other two (in proportion to their relative phase voltages).

> In the case of a delta circuit between current flows only between 2 nodes ...

On the delta configuration the current splits at each terminal and goes two ways. What comes in on one phase will go out on the other two (in proportion to their relative phase voltages).